# AutoIdentifying spatial reference from shapefile fails on second attempt

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, shapefile, c#

I read a shapefile with GDAL 2.4.3 in C# and try to determine the used spatial reference. This works fine for the first time reading the file. When I close the file and read it again, the determination fails. Here is my code for reproduction:

```
GdalConfiguration.ConfigureGdal();
GdalConfiguration.ConfigureOgr();
if (!GdalConfiguration.Usable)
  throw new Exception("GdalConfiguration failed");

var filename = @"someshapefile.shp";

for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
{
  using (var driver = OSGeo.OGR.Ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile"))
  using (var dataSource = driver.Open(filename, 0))
  using (var layer = dataSource.GetLayerByIndex(0))
  {
    layer.ResetReading();
    using (var feat = layer.GetNextFeature())
    using (var geom = feat.GetGeometryRef())
    {
      var spatRef = geom.GetSpatialReference();
      spatRef.AutoIdentifyEPSG();
      spatRef.ExportToWkt(out var wkt);
      Trace.WriteLine($"{i}. WKT = {wkt}");
      if (!int.TryParse(spatRef.GetAuthorityCode(null), out int srid) || srid <= 0)
        throw new Exception("unknown coordinate system."); // <= will be thrown when i = 2; srid is 0 then
    }
  }
}
```

The output differs for both attempts:

> 1. WKT = PROJCS["ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N (zE-N)",GEOGCS["ETRS89",DATUM["European_Terrestrial_Reference_System_1989",SPHEROID["GRS
>      1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6258"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4258"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",9],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",32500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4647"]]

which is correctly identified as [4647](https://epsg.io/4647).

> 2. WKT = PROJCS["ETRS_1989_UTM_Zone_N32",GEOGCS["GCS_ETRS_1989",DATUM["European_Terrestrial_Reference_System_1989",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",32500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",9.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

which results in `srid == 0`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Both the PROJCS and GEOGCS name strings are different.

Comment: Sorry I am not good at reading C# but where in your code you close the shapefile?

Comment: @user30184 The `using` scope does the dispose at the end of the scope.